# QML Button - How to check that button is pressed with Control modifier?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

How we can detect the QML button is clicked (checked) with "Control" key button pressed simultaniously?

Comment: You can't check that.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there's no way to check if the `CTRL` key is pressed while you're in an `onPressed` handler of a button, but you could work around that:

Let QML inform you when the `CTRL` key is pressed/released. Save that status in a property and use it in the `onPressed` handler of the button.

```
// Example code
Item {
    id: rootItem

    anchors.fill: parent
    focus: true
    property bool ctrlPressed: false
    Keys.onPressed: {
        if (event.key === Qt.Key_Control) {
            ctrlPressed = true
        }
    }
    Keys.onReleased: {
        if (event.key === Qt.Key_Control) {
            ctrlPressed = false
        }
    }

    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        text: "Press me"

        onPressed: {
            if (rootItem.ctrlPressed)
                console.log("Click with CTRL")
            else
                console.log("Click without CTRL")
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a 'workaround' and has some issues:

- The `rootItem` has to have the focus
- when the Application loses focus (`ALT`+`TAB` or minimize) while the `CTRL` button is pressed you might get unexpected behaviour

Comment: I would suggest to change your `event.key === Qt.Key_Control` to `event.modifiers & Qt.ControlModifier` check so it doesn't matter what was pressed. Only modifier matters. [Docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-keyevent.html#modifiers-prop)

Answer (score 2):

One more solution is to use a `TapHandler` (a relatively new feature, see [blog post](https://www.qt.io/blog/2017/11/23/say-hello-qt-quick-pointer-handlers)).

There's an [example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-treeviewdelegate.html#interacting-with-pointers) in the docs for a new `TreeViewDelegate` which can be modified for your case with `Button` (they both inherit `AbstractButton`).

This way you won't have to remember any state or propagate events to underlying internal mouse area of the button:

```
Button {
    text: "Test"

    TapHandler {
        acceptedModifiers: Qt.ControlModifier
        onTapped: console.log("tapped with Qt.ControlModifier")
    }

    TapHandler {
        acceptedModifiers: Qt.NoModifier
        onTapped: console.log("tapped with Qt.NoModifier")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is simply adding your own `MouseArea` on top of the button. You could use `propogateComposedEvents` to allow the `Button`'s default mouse handling to still occur, or you could manually regenerate things like the `clicked` signal yourself. Neither option is ideal, but maybe one works for you.

```
Button {
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        propagateComposedEvents: true

        onClicked: {
            if ((mouse.button == Qt.LeftButton) && (mouse.modifiers & Qt.ControlModifier)) {
                doSomething();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used @ParkerHalo's answer. The issue he noticed when the app loses focus with `ctrl` pressed can be avoided by placing this in the top level `Window`:

```
onActiveChanged:  if( ! active )  rootItem.ctrlPressed = false;
```

Comment: @eyllanesc, didn't understand your edit. My intention was just to complement ParkerHalo's answer, now seems I'm criticizing it.

Comment: Criticizing is never bad (unless they are with insults), and within the criticism you can say the code is good but in certain cases it fails so with the following code that complements it no longer fails. I do not see in which part a bad criticism is made or that ParkerHalo is upset. Please read [answer]. Here each action must be taken in good faith, unless it violates the code of conduct.

Comment: Edited again. There was nothing in "How to Answer" against my original post. In "How to Edit", there is "always respect the original author". Insults are not the only way of causing damage, and I don't want anything malicious being said in my name.